# sql syntax error 1064 in workbench-generated script

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm not very familiar with sql, so I'm using workbench to create a db. I keep getting this error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near ')
    REFERENCES `project2`.`REF` ()
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE' at line 6
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project2`.`REF_AUTH` (
          `REF#` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `RAUTHOR` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`REF#`, `RAUTHOR`),
          CONSTRAINT `REF#`
            FOREIGN KEY ()
            REFERENCES `project2`.`REF` ()
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = big5

SQL script execution finished: statements: 4 succeeded, 1 failed
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, your issue was the syntax with the foreign key and the references.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project2`.`REF_AUTH` (
  `REF#` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `RAUTHOR` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`REF#`, `RAUTHOR`),
   CONSTRAINT `REF#`
      FOREIGN KEY (`REF#`) REFERENCES `REF` (`REF#`) 
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE)
   ENGINE = InnoDB
   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = big5
```

[Syntax link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

[Another helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8434518/5149122)